# Зачем нужен std::endl?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Что значит `endl` в:

```
std::cout << "Таблица информации" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 9):

Важно заметить, что `std::endl` не только вставляет знак перевода строки. Вы можете вставлять **'\n'**, или **'\r\n'**, но вывод строки произойдет лишь в конце блока (программы) или при сбрасывании буфера.

`std::endl` *принудительно очищает буфер вывода*, и строка выводится сразу же вслед за этой командой.

Comment: Только не при переполнении, а при заполнении.

Answer (score 1):

Окончание строки. Также может использоваться спец.символ `"\n"`. Например, `cout<<"ПРИМЕР!\nТаблица информации";` выведет "ПРИМЕР" на одной строке, а "Таблица информации" на новой строке.

Answer (score 1):

```
ostream& endl ( ostream& os );
```

[Вставляет символ перевода строки](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/endl/) в данном случае после текста.

Answer (score -1):

**С**onsole**OUT** << [т.е. На нее] "TEXT" << **ENDL**ine