# Когда писать std::endl а когда '\n'?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Есть два способа записать перевод строки - `std::endl` и `\n`. В чем разница? Когда что использовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем нужен std::endl?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/54652/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-stdendl)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`std::endl` реализован как `os.put(os.widen(’\n’)); os.flush();`.
Соответственно всё отличие в том, что `endl` вызывает `flush()`, а `\n` - нет.

Вызов `flush()` очищает буфер потока, и если выполнять его слишком часто, он может ощутимо замедлить выполнение программы.

Также надо помнить что `std::endl` не нужен там где стандартная библиотека сама вызывает `cout.flush()`:

- при завершении программы
- при чтении из `std::cin`
- при записи в `std::cerr`

Некоторые реализации буферизуют вывод в stdout построчно, и запись `\n` сама будет вызывать `flush`.

Записать буфер можно явно, манипулятором `std::flush`, например

```
std::cout << "Calculating XYZ ... " << std::flush; wait_XYZ(); std::cout << "OK\n";
```

#### Ссылки

- [Описание `endl` на cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)

Comment: Ещё по теме: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf

Comment: Ещё от меня, чуточку по теме, но когда использовать cout, cerr, clog: http://htrd.su/wiki/zhurnal/2016/03/15/std_cout_std_cerr_i_std_clog

Comment: Я бы еще добавил что `std::endl` удобно вызывать когда у нас есть буфер который необходимо вывести, т.к. у буфера может не быть `\n`.

Answer (score -6):

Надо помнить, что в с++ файлы сами не закрываются при выходе из проги. Может и закрываются, но только в памяти, а на диске файл будет не виден. Правильно сказал предыдущий человек: смотря какую цель преследуете. Возможно не нужно так часто флашить, особенно в цикле.

Пишите "@": чтоб на почту пришло. Я случайно увидел ваш коммент. По сути: нет потоки само не закрывает (по крайней мере на диске). Приходится в деструкторе объекта указывать `close()`, чтоб файл был на диске. В паскале проще: там можно не указывать закрытие, при выходе из проги само закроет.

Comment: Прошу пояснить, желательно с примерами кода. Использование потоков для взаимодействия с файлами автоматически закрывает их (файлы) при разрушении объекта.