# Инспекция: нахождение корней квадратного уравнения на C++

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Помогите, как можно улучшить программу по нахождению корней квадратного уравнения.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

double dis(double a, double b, double c);//Псевдоним функции по нахождению дискриминанта

int main()// main функция
{
   double a, b, c, xa, xb, disb;//переменные, необходимые для программы
   cout << "Введите коэфиециент а: ";// Следующие строчки это сбор данных
   cin >> a;
   cout << a << endl;
   cout << "Введите коэфиециент b: ";
   cin >> b;
   cout << b << endl;
   cout << "Введите свободное слагаемое с: ";
   cin >> c;
   cout << c << endl;
   cout << "КОНЕЧНЫЙ ВИД: " << a << "x^2" << "+(" << b << ")" << "x" << "+(" << c << ")" << "=0" << endl;//выводит конечный вид уравнения
   double ld;//переменная, в которую будет записан возвращаемый результат функции dis()
   ld = dis(a, b, c);// запись
   if (ld < 0)//ветвление для защиты от отрицательного дискриминаната
   {
      cout << "Ой, все, решений нет." << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      disb = sqrt(ld); //вычисляем квадратный корень
      xa = ((-b) + disb) / (2 * a);// находим корни
      xb = ((-b) - disb) / (2 * a);
      cout << "ПЕРВЫЙ Х РАВЕН: " << xa << endl;//выводим корни
      cout << "ВТОРОЙ Х РАВЕН: " << xb << endl;
   }
}

double dis(double a, double b, double c)// функця по нахождению дискриминанта
{
   double xld;
   xld = ((b*b) - (4 * a*c));
   cout << "Дискриминант равен: " << xld << endl;
   return xld;
}
```

Comment: Я приклеил соответствующую метку, рекомендую прочесть её описание. Возможно, вы захотите немножко дополнить/поправить вопрос.

Comment: Речь идет о C++ или простом С? Потому что пока тут от плюсов только использование cin и cout

Comment: Newman, это C++

Comment: @Alexander Тут даже переменные объявлены, как в С - сразу скопом в начале функции... От C++ тут только потоки ввода-вывода. Кстати, зачем после ввода переменной вы сразу же ее выводите?

Но я хотел задать другой вопрос - ладно с дискриминантом, но если кто-то введет `a=0`, что получится?.. а что должно? :)

Comment: Если а будет 0, то просто первое слагаемое сократится и будет неполное квадратное уравнение, но ответы будут, причем правильные, если подставить.

Comment: @AlexanderDremov, это был намек, что вот тут: `xa=((-b)+disb)/(2*a);` будет деление на 0

Comment: Черт, не заметил, еще ветвление надо делать, если a - 0, то x = c/b

Comment: @AlexanderDremov на самом деле, `x = -c/b` в таком случае.

Comment: Да, уже исправил              if (a==0)    
               {       xa=(-c/b);
                       cout<<"Линейное уравнение. Ответ : "<<xa<<endl;
               }

Comment: Решение квадратного уравнения - одна из задач, которая может сильно страдать от особенностей поведения плавающей арифметики. Причем это "страдание" можно существенно победить, если делать вычисления немножко хитрее. В частности, на эту тему есть старая статья George Forsythe http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/66/40/CS-TR-66-40.pdf

Comment: Формально это С++, но от С++ в этом коде, конечно, одно название

Comment: Если кто-нибудь своим ответом-таки решил вашу проблему, то не поленитесь отметить ответ "галочкой" (рядом со "стрелочками" у ответов), чтобы он не висел в списке неотвеченных :)

Answer (score 15):

Программу можно "улучшить" так: решать не так в лоб, как когда-то в школьной тетрадке писали, а с учетом особенностей поведения компьютерной плавающей арифметики. В частности, существенно лучшим в этом отношении является следующий подход к решению

```
double d = b * b - 4 * a * c; // Дискриминант

double q = b >= 0 ? (-b - sqrt(d)) / 2  : (-b + sqrt(d)) / 2; 
// Здесь узнается наше родное `-b +- sqrt(d) / 2 * a`, 
// но пока что без `a` в знаменателе

double x1 = q / a;
double x2 = c / q;
```

Те, кто знаком с [формулами Виета](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0), легко увидят и математическую правильность решения. А вот почему следует поступать именно так, можно почитать в [классической статье](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/66/40/CS-TR-66-40.pdf) (а на русском языке - у Моулера, Малькольма и того же Форсайта в книге "Машинные методы математических вычислений")

Вкратце, идея заключается в том, что в плавающей арифметике во избежание потери точности рекомендуется избегать сложения относительно больших чисел, близких по абсолютному значению, но имеющих разные знаки - результат может получиться катастрофически неточным. В "лобовом" решении подвыражение `-b - sqrt(d)` может страдать от этой проблемы, если `b` отрицательно. Вышеприведенный подход при вычислении промежуточной величины `q` всегда выполняет сложение чисел с одинаковыми знаками.

Answer (score 8):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
```

Рекомендуется сортировать заголовочные файлы по алфавиту (и группировать свои и системные), меньше шансов что один будет неявно зависеть от другого, всегда понятно в какое место вставить новый.

```
using namespace std;
```

Никогда не пишите `using namespace std;`, особенно в глобальном пространстве имен. Это приводит к конфликтам имен, причем иногда ошибки компиляции не будет, но программа будет вызывать какую-то стандартную функцию вместо Вашей.

```
double dis(double a, double b, double c);//Псевдоним функции по нахождению дискриминанта
```

Это называется "декларация" или объявление функции, а не псевдоним. Нет никакого смысла ее тут использовать. Пишите свои функции в начале, в main() в конце программы.
Не надо экономить на буквах. Переименуйте в `discriminant`.

```
int main()// main функция
```

No shit bro. Не надо писать бессмысленные коментарии, и так понятно что она main и что она функция.

```
{
   double a, b, c, xa, xb, disb;//переменные, необходимые для программы
```

Не надо объявлять несколько несвязанных переменных в одной декларации ([ES10](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md)). Объявляйте переменные только в месте их использования ([ES21](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md)) и всегда их инициализируйте ([ES20](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md)) (если есть чем).

```
   cout << "Введите коэфиециент а: ";// Следующие строчки это сбор данных
```

Не надо писать комментарии, пишите код. Вынесите это в функцию `void collect_input(double& a, double& b, double& c)` или лучше `Coefficients read_coefficients(std::istream& stream)`, тогда название функции будет говорить о том что тут делается.

```
   cin >> a;
   cout << a << endl;
```

[Здесь не нужен endl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420485/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-stdendl-%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-n), используйте '\n'.

```
   cout << "Введите коэфиециент b: ";
   cin >> b;
   cout << b << endl;
   cout << "Введите свободное слагаемое с: ";
   cin >> c;
   cout << c << endl;
   cout << "КОНЕЧНЫЙ ВИД: " << a << "x^2" << "+(" << b << ")" << "x" << "+(" << c << ")" << "=0" << endl;//выводит конечный вид уравнения
```

Не надо писать бессмысленные комментарии, в сообщении уже написано что это.
Сложный код лучше выносить в отдельные функции, например `print_formula(a, b, c);`

```
   double ld;//переменная, в которую будет записан возвращаемый результат функции dis()
   ld = dis(a, b, c);// запись
```

Должно быть `double dis = discriminant(a, b, c);`. Почему вообще **l**d? Не используйте непонятные сокращения. Также лучше использовать вывод типов: `auto dis = ...;`

```
   if (ld < 0)//ветвление для защиты от отрицательного дискриминаната
   {
      cout << "Ой, все, решений нет." << endl;
```

Не надо мешать в одну кучу вычисление корней уранения, обработку случая отсутствия корней и логирование ошибок.
Вынесите вычисление корней в отдельную функцию, например 
`bool try_solve(const Coefficients& a, Roots& x)`. Альтернативный вариант - `std::vector<double> solve(const std::vector<double>& coeffs)`.

```
   }
   else
   {
      disb = sqrt(ld); //вычисляем квадратный корень
      xa = ((-b) + disb) / (2 * a);// находим корни
      xb = ((-b) - disb) / (2 * a);
```

Должно быть `auto xa = ...;` или `double xa = ...;`

```
      cout << "ПЕРВЫЙ Х РАВЕН: " << xa << endl;//выводим корни
      cout << "ВТОРОЙ Х РАВЕН: " << xb << endl;
   }
}

double dis(double a, double b, double c)// функця по нахождению дискриминанта
{
   double xld;
   xld = ((b*b) - (4 * a*c));
   cout << "Дискриминант равен: " << xld << endl;
   return xld;
}
```

Не надо засовывать логи в вычисления. Если так хочется залогировать дискриминант, напишите класс или структуру, которая будет хранить промежуточные результаты вычислений, и потом их логируйте. Например:

```
struct QuadraticEquation {
  QuadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}

  bool solve() {
    discr = calc_discriminant();
    if (discr < 0) return false;
    x1 = ...
    return true;
  }

  double a, b, c;
  double discr;
  double x0, x1;
};
```

В крайнем случае можно вычислить дискриминант второй раз, если так хочется его залогировать.

Comment: _"Никогда не пишите `using namespace std;`", "Не надо объявлять несколько несвязанных переменных в одной декларации ..."_ - не согласен.

Comment: @Abyx Вот принцип, по которому `using namespace` не пишется в хедерах весьма очевиден, а вот в _cpp-шниках_ не столь понятен. Ведь люди сознательно вставляют такие конструкции в _cpp-шники_ чтобы избежать многословности в тех случая, когда функции из разных пространств имен не пересекаются, контролируя последствия, ну, или по крайней, мере, люди с опытом контролируют :)

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, имеет смысл:

1. Вынести функцию решения квадратного уравнения:

   ```
   int solve(double a, double b, double c, double *x1, double *x2)
   ```

   a, b, с - коэффициенты
   возвращаемое значение - количество корней (или -1 если их бесконечно много)
   *x1, *x2 - сами корни (если корней меньше двух, лишние переменные не трогаем)
2. Сравнивать дробные числа с некоторой точностью EPS, например, 1e-7.
   В том числе, сравнить дискриминант с нулём как `fabs(d) < EPS`.
3. Убрать функцию вычисления дискриминанта.
4. Ввод и вывод оставить в main'е.

Comment: @Abyx, чтобы визуально было заметно, что туда делается запись. Но можно и ссылки - это на усмотрение пишущего :)

Comment: @Abyx, при вызове. `n = f(a, b, c, x1, x2)` или `n = f(a, b, c, &x1, &x2)` - где заметнее, что здесь out?

Comment: @Abyx, и все же (imho, конечно же) ссылки наряду  с перегрузкой функций это (при чтении чужого кода) неприятные вещи в крестах.

Answer (score 1):

Код с минимальными правками (подправил алгоритм):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double EPS = 1E-5;

static bool isEqual(const double& left, const double& right, const double& eps = EPS)
{
   return abs(left - right) < EPS;
}

double dis(double a, double b, double c);//Псевдоним функции по нахождению дискриминанта

int main()// main функция
{
   double a, b, c, xa, xb, disb;//переменные, необходимые для программы
   cout << "Введите коэфиециент а: ";// Следующие строчки это сбор данных
   cin >> a;
   cout << a << endl;
   cout << "Введите коэфиециент b: ";
   cin >> b;
   cout << b << endl;
   cout << "Введите свободное слагаемое с: ";
   cin >> c;
   cout << c << endl;
   cout << "КОНЕЧНЫЙ ВИД: " << a << "x^2" << "+(" << b << ")" << "x" << "+(" << c << ")" << "=0" << endl;//выводит конечный вид уравнения
   double ld = dis(a, b, c);//переменная, в которую будет записан возвращаемый результат функции dis()
   if (ld < 0.0)//ветвление для защиты от отрицательного дискриминаната
   {
      cout << "Ой, все, решений нет." << endl;
   }
   else if (isEqual(0.0, a))
   {
      if (isEqual(0.0, b))
      {
         if (isEqual(0.0, c))
            cout << "Существует бесконечное множество решений." << endl;
         else
            cout << "Ой, все, решений нет." << endl;
      }
      else
         cout << "Х РАВЕН: " << -c/b << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      disb = sqrt(ld); //вычисляем квадратный корень
      if (isEqual(0.0, b))
      {
         cout << "Х РАВЕН: " << disb / (2*a) << endl;
      }
      else
      {
         xa = (-b + disb) / (2*a);// находим корни
         xb = (-b - disb) / (2*a);
         cout << "ПЕРВЫЙ Х РАВЕН: " << xa << endl;//выводим корни
         cout << "ВТОРОЙ Х РАВЕН: " << xb << endl;
      }
   }
}

double dis(double a, double b, double c)// функця по нахождению дискриминанта
{
   double xld;
   xld = b*b - 4*a*c;
   cout << "Дискриминант равен: " << xld << endl;
   return xld;
}
```

Если вам не принципиально выдавать доп. информацию для пользователя в функции `dis`, то сразу напишите там `return b*b - 4*a*c;` во благо срабатывания `RVO`, либо вообще откажитесь от данной функции (ведь вы её используете всего 1 раз), ну, либо можете извратиться и запехнуть это в макрос, например `#define dis(a, b, c) b*b - 4*a*c`.
Ну и всю логику решения (именно решения задачи, а не ввода данных), по-моему, неплохо бы вынести в отдельную функцию хотя бы.

---

**P.S.**
По заявкам желающих сделал все как вы любите (аля *C-style*, кроме потоков ввода/вывода, конечно), зато сколько внимания уделили такому, на первый взгляд, неприметному вопросу в сообществе (автору, наверное, приятно). И, да, хорошо потроллили, [молодцы](http://media.professionali.ru/processor/topics/original/2013/03/18/trollface-hd.jpg) :)

Comment: Ну и зачем тут ООП???

Comment: @Qwertiy ну ведь жутко же неудобно, когда взаимосвязанные функции просто разбросаны по коду или у вас другой взгляд на данный вопрос?

Comment: Другой. Нужна одна функция для решения уравнения. Всё.

Comment: @Qwertiy т.е. вы обычно не рефакторите свой код?

Comment: Тогда уж все внутренние функции оставить приватными, наружу выставить метод solve без параметров и вставить возможность возврата комплексных корней, т.к. решение есть всегда и их всегда 2. Это если полностью в ООП стиле. А так, излишества все это.

Comment: Не помню, как оно точно звучало, но примерно так: "можно написать простой код, в котором, очевидно, нет ошибок; а можно сложный, в котором нет очевидных ошибок" ;)

Comment: И вообще, а где в твоём коде ООП? Единственный класс, все методы которого статические. Причём, этот класс не только решает уравнение, но и занимается вводом-выводом. И он не просто совмещает эти обязанности, но и совмещает их таким образом, что использование класса для решения уравнения без ввода коэффициентов пользователем, или без вывода ответа невозможно.

Comment: А еще можно фабрику по производству фабрик молотков прикрутить... Квадратное уравнение...

Comment: @andy.37, было бы не плохо, прикрутите? ;-)

Comment: @Grundy, староват я для этого)))

Comment: @Abyx, запилите что-то функционально? :)

Comment: Да ну вас нафиг, хотел просто помочь человеку, а вы демагогию развели, да еще и засрали тут все что можно :)

Comment: @Abyx Ок, я вас понял, сейчас напишу как требуют желающие :)

Comment: По-моему, вы ошиблись в самом начале. [tag:инспекция-кода] не про "отрефакторьте мне код", а про критику: комментарии к строчкам и структуре предложенного кода и пояснения, что там стоит поправить, как это называется и почему. А так вы предоставили свой вариант кода, и [tag:инспекция-кода] началась уже над вашим кодом, а код в вопросе остался почти без внимания :}

Comment: @D-side Теперь и я это понял и приму к сведению, а то тролли не дремлют :)

Comment: @D-side, а может под *инспекцией кода* каждый понимает все же что-то свое, и не факт, что Ваше понимание должно быть истиной для всех.

Comment: @avp возможно, но моё понимание основано на наблюдении за CodeReview.SE. Да и голоса за другие ответы к этому же вопросу это подтверждают.