# Простой калькулятор c++

Tags: c++

Недавно начал изучать программирование, и решил начать с освоения c++. Попытался создать простой калькулятор, но почему-то в командной строке показывает только первого оператора `cout`:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int a, b;  
    cout << "4 ";
    cin >> a; 
    cout << "4 ";
    cin >> b;
    int c = a + b;  
    cout << "8 " << c << endl;   
    return 0;
}
```

Выводит: "4 "

Comment: Почитайте [Когда писать std::endl а когда '\n'?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420485/Когда-писать-stdendl-а-когда-n/420486#420486)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что после cout у вас в коде стоит cin, который блокирует выполнение приложения, пока вы не введете что-то.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понимаю что это за "cout << "4"". cin команда которая ждет, пока вы что-то введете(введите значение и нажмите энтер), делать это нужно прямиком в консоль. Команда cout просто выводит в консоль то, что вы задали ей. Т.е. в вашем случае нам нужно записать числа, любые, например 2 и 7, тогда ваша консоль будет выглядеть так:

```
4 //это вывела программа
2 //это вы ввели
4 //это вывела программа
7 //это вы ввели
8 9 //это вывела программа
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы, видимо, не совсем поняли смысл cout и cin. Если вы хотите сами вводить значения чисел А и B, то используйте cin, если хотите ввывести число или надпись на экран, то cout. Если вы хотите задать их заранее, то используйте оператор "=", т.е. A=4 и т.д.
А вот программа, в которой вы вводите два числа и она выдаёт вам их сумму:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int A, B, C;
    cout << "Введите число A:" << '\n';
    cin >> A;
    cout << "Введите число B:" << '\n';
    cin >> B;
    C = A + B;
    cout << "C=" << C << '\n';
    system("pause");
}
```